What is a restricted JavaScript object?
I'm trying to use custom DOM events to communicate between the main world and the isolated world for a page in a webextension in Firefox. When trying to access an event object property, I get an access denied error. Most of what follows is just context. I really want to know what a "restricted" object is rather than how to make it unrestricted.
listener
function onCustom( e ) {
  console.log( e );
  console.log( e.detail );
  console.log( e.detail.plugh );
}
document.addEventListener( 'custom', onCustom );

sender
e = new CustomEvent( 'custom', { detail: {
  plugh: 'xyzzy'
} } );

document.dispatchEvent( e );

If the listener and the sender are both in the same world, it works fine. (This case is just a sanity check, since the point is to communicate between worlds.)
If the listener is in the isolated world and the sender is in the main world, it works fine.
If the listener is in the main world and the sender is in the isolated world, it pukes as follows.
console output
custom { blah, blah, blah, lots of properties }
Object { plugh: "xyzzy" }
Uncaught Error: Permission denied to access property "plugh"

That's all the error information that there is: an untyped error and a message string.
I can expand the Object (second line) in the devtools console. It's there.
If I expand the "custom" object (first line) in the devtools console, it says (in part):
  detail: Restricted {  }

The detail property of a CustomEvent can be anything serializable. I can do my own serialization with JSON.stringify() in the sender and deserialize it with JSON.parse() in the listener. It's a workaround that does work. I still want to know what's going on with the object that I cannot access it after it was serialized and deserialized transparently for me.
EDIT (from the comments): The documented way to send objects from the isolated world into the main world is cloneInto().
sender (isolated to main only)
e = new CustomEvent( 'custom', cloneInto( { detail: {
  plugh: 'xyzzy'
} }, wrappedJSObject ) );

document.dispatchEvent( e );


What do you mean by "same world"? Do you mean how browser extensions' run in a separate execution context? Is your script running in a Background-script context or a Content-script context?

@Dai, the content world is either main or isolated. The web page loaded from a server is the "main" world. The default world for an extension content script is "isolated." Nothing in this question is in the background.

"(This case is just a sanity check, since the point is to communicate between worlds.)" -- I only have experience with Chrome Extensions, not Firefox, but in Chrome you cannot use synchronous-ish DOM features (like addEventListener) and instead must perform all extension-to-page (and vice-versa) communications using
message-passing techniques - so all objects/values passed around must be serializable.

A restricted JavaScript object refers to an object that exists in a context (or world) where access is limited or blocked due to security and isolation policies. In the context of your issue with Firefox web extensions, this behavior arises from the separation between content scripts (isolated world) and the web page's JavaScript environment (main world)

@Dai, I'm not communicating with the background. The page you linked is for communicating between content and background. My example is more like calling .click() on an element. Everything is in the content context, but one is in one world and one is in the other. Also, events are asynchronous. I'm not sure why you think they're synchronous(-ish).

@Nanigashi I don't want to sidetrack the QA post, I've deleted my off-topic comment.

Firefox implements a structured clone algorithm to transfer data across world while maintaining isolation. If an object cannot be fully cloned or if it's flagged as unsafe, it becomes a restricted object.
This ensures that:

Sensitive data doesn't leak across contexts.
Malicious scripts cannot tamper with objects from secure origins.

In your case, the detail object, although serializable, is wrapped as Restricted when accessed from the main world. This ensures that extensions cannot inadvertently expose sensitive or insecure data to the webpage.

@DavidAniebo, do you mean window.wrappedJSObject (or like it), even though it's not a window property?

Simply use cloneInto function as explained in Firefox's documentation.

@woxxom, that works. Thanks, although the question was more about how the object is restricted (the mechanism, not the justification), rather than how to make it unrestricted. (Hmm, maybe I'll clarify that in the question.)

It's restricted because the extension's context (world) is more privileged. Use cloneInto to downgrade it. That's how Firefox decided to implement sharing, apparently to ensure you don't accidentally leak data into the page.

@DavidAniebo, would you write up your comment as an answer?

If, when "trying to access an event object property, [you] get an access denied error", remember to show that error in your post.

okay I will be adding it as an answer @Nanigashi

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I do show the error (all of it) in the console output. The only abbreviation of the output I did was not to list all the properties of the event object (blah, blah, blah). Unfortunately, the error message isn't especially informative. It doesn't even have a type.

This answer represents what I've learned today from (what I can remember of) a deleted answer from another poster plus the comments.
Because it's structured data, when sending { detail: { plugh: "xyzzy" } } in an event, the browser makes a structured clone. A common example of structured cloning is passing objects back and forth between realms with web workers. The question doesn't deal with web workers, but the main and isolated worlds of the content context are different realms, which have different window objects. (Having different window objects is part of how the isolation of "isolated world" works, even though the main and isolated worlds share the DOM and, hence, DOM events. That part I already knew.)
When Firefox serializes the detail object, the object (or at least members of it) retains the characterization of belonging to the isolated world. (I would have thought serialization discards it, but it doesn't.) In the main world, the deserialized object still belongs to the isolated world. Because the isolated world has a higher privilege level, the deserialized object is inaccessible ("restricted") in the main world.
Explicitly serializing the object with JSON.stringify() does discard the realm information, so the object can be deserialized without the origin realm information (and it works). Primitives, like strings, apparently don't have realm information. Mozilla has another solution for content scripts, however.
cloneInto() sets the realm information to whatever else is specified, usng the window of the target realm. Since wrappedJSObject is a reference in the isolated world to the window object in the main world, detail can be characterized as belonging to the main world before serialization. When it's deserialized, it still belongs to the main world, so it is accessible (not "restricted") in the main world.
TL;DR: Serialization and deserialization across the main/isolated world boundary retains world information for complex data. Objects belonging to the higher-privileged isolated world are restricted from access in the lower-privileged main world.
